# How to create radio buttons and drop down menu bar in Swift (for iOS app development)?

Tags: ios, swift, radio-button

I am beginner in iOS app development and am creating an app where I need to create radio button and drop sown menu bar using swift .
Please suggest me, how could I do that ??

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31936056/1627959) thread covers radio buttons well.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to SO. In general, this site isn't really suited to `"show me how to do <development task>"` questions. It's intended for specific technical questions about code you are trying to get working.

I'll take pity on you since this is your first post.

Neither radio buttons nor drop-down menus are standard iOS controls. You should consider using iOS standard user interface elements instead.

The iOS equivalent of radio buttons is a segmented control (UISegementedControl)

The iOS equivalent of a drop-down menu is a UIPickerView.

If you really want radio buttons and drop-down menus you could create them yourself, but as a beginner that is likely over your head. You might want to look for open source  components that do what you need. Try checking out [**CocoaControls**](https://www.cocoacontrols.com). There are lots and lots of custom controls. You can likely find what you're looking for there under a reasonable source license like the MIT license.