# multiple radio button in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have four different radio for different purpose. I have added the same selector for all four. And in selector method I have written code to for all four type of radio button. So it increases number of lines. So what is the best way to write the same code.

```
(void)checkBoxSelected:(id)sender{    
  switch ([sender tag]) {
    case 1:
        if([checkBoxDisel isSelected]==YES)
        {
            [checkBoxDisel setSelected:NO];
            [checkBoxPetrol setSelected:NO];
        }
        else{
            [checkBoxDisel setSelected:YES];
            [checkBoxPetrol setSelected:NO];
        }

        break;
    case 2:
        if([checkBoxPetrol isSelected]==YES)
        {
            [checkBoxPetrol setSelected:NO];
            [checkBoxDisel setSelected:NO];
        }
        else{
            [checkBoxPetrol setSelected:YES];
            [checkBoxDisel setSelected:NO];
        }
        break;
    case 3:
        if([checkBoxYes isSelected]==YES)
        {
            [checkBoxYes setSelected:NO];
            [checkBoxNo setSelected:NO];
        }
        else{
            [checkBoxYes setSelected:YES];
            [checkBoxNo setSelected:NO];
        }

        break;
    case 4:
        if([checkBoxNo isSelected]==YES)
        {
            [checkBoxNo setSelected:NO];
            [checkBoxYes setSelected:NO];
        }
        else{
            [checkBoxNo setSelected:YES];
            [checkBoxYes setSelected:NO];
        }
        break;
    case 5:
        if([checkBoxMale isSelected]==YES)
        {
            [checkBoxMale setSelected:NO];
            [checkBoxFemale setSelected:NO];
        }
        else{
            [checkBoxMale setSelected:YES];
            [checkBoxFemale setSelected:NO];
        }

        break;
    case 6:
        if([checkBoxFemale isSelected]==YES)
        {
            [checkBoxFemale setSelected:NO];
            [checkBoxMale setSelected:NO];
        }
        else{
            [checkBoxFemale setSelected:YES];
            [checkBoxMale setSelected:NO];
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
  }
}
```

Comment: `UISegmentedControl`, maybe... or surely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following lines:

```
if([checkBoxYes isSelected]==YES)
{
    [checkBoxYes setSelected:NO];
    [checkBoxNo setSelected:NO];
}
else{
    [checkBoxYes setSelected:YES];
    [checkBoxNo setSelected:NO];
}
```

can be rewritten as

```
checkBoxYes.selected = !checkBoxYes.selected;
checkBoxNo.selected = NO;
```

And the same goes for every case in your huge `switch`.

Have you considered using segmented controls instead?

Comment: doesn't `checkBoxNo.selected = NO;` should be `checkBoxNo.selected = !checkBoxYes.selected;`

Comment: It should IMHO, but here I've just refactored the OP's code, mistakes included. In this case it helps to spot the problem.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the radio button alternative in iOS is the segmented control.

If you would like to use your own buttons, I recommend to use `IBOutletCollection` instead of simple `IBOutlet`. As a result you won't have 4 different button with different names, you will have an array with the buttons and you are able to iterate through the array and set the selected one to 'selected' state, and unselect the others.

```
    for (UIButton *radioButton in radioButtons) {
        if (radioButton.tag == [sender tag]) {
            [radioButton setSelected:YES];
        }
        else {
            [radioButton setSelected:NO];
        }
    }
```

Where `radioButtons` is the `IBOutletCollection` array containing the radio buttons.

Furthermore it would be ideal to create a separated object (called e.g. YZRadioControl) which is going to contain the buttons and responsible for managing the selection. And of course it would be customisable. Like [this](https://github.com/onegray/RadioButton-ios) or [this](https://github.com/frederik-jacques/TNRadioButtonGroup) or maybe [this](https://github.com/DavydLiu/DLRadioButton) or perhaps [this](https://github.com/vcepeda858/VCRadioButton/)...

Good luck for coding!

Comment: plus 1 : for using for loop... But for sure, OP will confuse in radioButtons as array...

Answer (score 1):

In sender, you can access to button:

```
 UIButton* myButton = (UIButton*)sender;
```

Easy way is iterate through all UIbutton objects and set as disabled and enable this button.

```
-(void)checkBoxSelected:(id)sender{
    for (UIButton *radioButton in radioButtons) {
        [radioButton setSelected:NO];
    }
    UIButton* myButton = (UIButton*)sender;
    [myButton setSelected:YES];
    //or
    //[sender setSelected:YES];
}
```

variable radioButtons contains all UIButton objects.